# awk + sed + match complex string

Tags: linux, sed, perl, solaris, awk

I need useful command to match the string "/pci.../pci.../pci..../scsi..../disk..."
with awk or sed? ( I need to put this command in my ksh script )

remark 1 [...] can be any string , and “pci pci pci scsi disk”  are default strings
remark 2 I have Solaris machine so syntax should fit Solaris

example

```
       prtpicl -v |grep :disk0 | awk '{print $2}'
```

give the output

```
       /pci@0/pci@0/pci@2/scsi@0/disk@0
```

Comment: `[...]` can *not* be any string. it would probably be very bad if it were to contain `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
prtpicl -v \
| egrep ':disk0.*/pci[^/]+/pci[^/]+/pci[^/]+/scsi[^/]+/disk' \
| awk '{print $2}'
```

For example

```
$ cat prtpicl.out
Some headings blah blah
:disk0 some uninteresting stuff
:disk0 /pci@0/pci@0/pci@2/scsi@0/disk@0
:disk1 /pci@0/pci@0/pci@2/scsi@0/disk@1
Last line

$ cat prtpicl.out \
> | egrep ':disk0.*/pci[^/]+/pci[^/]+/pci[^/]+/scsi[^/]+/disk' \
> | awk '{print $2}'
/pci@0/pci@0/pci@2/scsi@0/disk@0
```

Comment: prtpicl -v | grep ':disk0.*/pci[^/]*/pci[^/]+/pci[^/]+/scsi[^/]+/disk'   not match the  /pci@0/pci@0/pci@2/scsi@0/disk@0 ? (I try it on my solaris machine )

Comment: echo "/pci@0/pci@0/pci@2/scsi@0/disk@0" | egrep ':disk0.*/pci[^/]*/pci[^/]+/pci[^/]+/scsi[^/]+/disk' - its also not match on linux but I need this for my solaris machine

Comment: @Eytan: I don't have a Sun computer. What exactly is the output of `prtpicl -v | grep disk0`?

Comment: prtpicl -v | grep disk0 GIVE YOU -->     :disk0 /pci@0/pci@0/pci@2/scsi@0/disk@0

Comment: @Eytan: It works for me. See updated answer. Maybe egrep on Sun boxen is different. I'll check my old Solaris manual later.